# Install an old python module with respective old dependencies

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, pyinstaller

I have been trying to install a python module called OBITools (https://pythonhosted.org/OBITools/welcome.html, https://anaconda.org/bioconda/obitools) that was designed to python 2.7. Apart from the installation strategy, it will invariably call a script called 'get-obitools.py' (https://pythonhosted.org/OBITools/_downloads/get-obitools.py). However, the 'get-obitools.py' script, even when called from python 2.7 will try to install up-to-date dependencies. By doing so, the installation will be trapped in an infinite loop because it will fail to install certain dependencies, usually due to python syntax change in the most recent python versions, i.e.:

```
print(error, file=sys.stderr)
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have to say that I am not a heavy python user. Thus, I might be missing something basic here. However, it is really strange to me that basic syntax changed from python2 to python3. It seems logic that such huge change would break old modules at some point. In fact, it may be the case for OBITools as show above.

In summary, is it possible to force OBITools installation to search for old dependencies (i.e. versions that worked at python 2.7) while installing?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple and illogical hack to fix this issue.
you can simply remove argument name from source code of `get-obitools.py`.
**For Example**
your code will become

```
print(error, sys.stderr)
```

And this is not a huge change, It's basic change in python 2.x print was not a function but in python 3.x it's a function

Comment: Maybe I was not completely clear. I am not able to rewrite the whole OBITools to make it work in python3 syntax as it would be a Homeric effort and might cause unexpected behavior in the functionalities in such a widely-used module. Thus, I need to run it in python 2.7. What I need is to force OBITools installation to get old versions of the dependencies (i.e. those working on python 2.7 specifically). In summary, I want to go back in time and install OBITools when python 2.7 was the most recent python version out there.